# Moving to Detroit temporarily?

Tags: usa, residency, safety

I have to shift to the Detroit area for job search as the recruiting companies for my job role are all located in the surrounding area (Farmington Hills, Dearborn, Livonia, Troy, Novi, Plymouth, etc). The problem is that I want to move temporarily because I may get a job even outside Detroit. Most home searches I found require signing a lease for like a year.

1. Which area within the Detroit area is safe and economical? Asking because I would not be earning for that time and would be depending mostly on my savings.
2. Are there any websites/groups/forums, etc where I can search for homes that require only monthly payment?

If my post is not appropriate for this forum then please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Note to the off-topic close voters. It was suggested on Travel that this question was a better fit for Expatriates because of the desire to rent a place for 2-3 months in order to job hunt.

Answer (score 3):

Most US apartment complexes and other houses for rent requires a 12 month lease. Some also offers a 6 month lease at a higher monthly rent.
It is very rare to find a month-to-month lease, and if you do they are usually much more expensive.

If you know you only want to rent for 2-3 months initially you can rent a furnished apartment, perhaps through HomeAway or Airbnb. It will be a bit more expensive, but then you don't have to buy furniture, cookware, etc.